# Internal storage not storing file on my device

Tags: android

Hi friends have lot of confusion.
 First thing is it's not storing in on my device instead of it stores on my emulator under this path data/data/com.customfonts/files/Robotoo.ttf. Then when I try to get file throwing Runtime Exception  file not found because it's searching under data/user/0/com.customfonts/Robotoo.ttf instead of searching data.data/com.customfonts/files/Robotoo.ttf.

```
 getDirectory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            new DownloadingTask().execute();
            Log.i("FilePAthFirst",""+getFilesDir());
        }
    });
    btnGETDATA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String filename="Robotoo.ttf";

            getTypeface(filename);
         }
    });

    private Typeface getTypeface(String filename)
    {

        Typeface font;
        try
        {

            font = Typeface.createFromFile(getFilesDir() +"/"+filename);
            Log.i("FOnt found",""+font);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }


    return  font;
}

private class DownloadingTask  extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(fonturl);
            HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");
            c.connect();


            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir()+ "Robotoo.ttf");
            Log.i("Download","complete");
            Log.i("FOS",""+fos.toString());

            InputStream is = c.getInputStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len1 = 0;
            while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
            }
            fos.close();
            is.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            outputFile = null;
            Log.e("Error", "Download Error Exception " + e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Harmonize the code to get the file path for saving the file and loading the file.

To load the tff also use getApplicationContext().getFilesDir()+filename

Answer (score 0):

I used your same code, which is in answer it working fine, May be you can check you have permission for the internet in Manifest `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>`, if you already have this, You can wait till `onPostExecute` of your `AsyncTask` and check you are getting any error.

**Internal storage**

And For internal storage, It will not be constant as `data.data/com.customfonts/files/` from Android 6.0, It will be dynamic, We should not hard code the path(You are doing that is correct)

Refer this [Offical Doc](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0.html#adoptable-storage)

Edited: Forgot to Add earlier that to writing a file in internal storage as per doc we should use `openFileOutput` so I am using that.

```
private class DownloadingTask  extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("[your url here]");
            HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");
            c.connect();

            Log.d("sdsdfds", "doInBackground: " + getApplicationContext().getFilesDir());

            FileOutputStream fos = getApplicationContext().openFileOutput("Robotoo4.ttf", MODE_PRIVATE);
            Log.i("Download","complete");
            Log.i("FOS",""+fos.toString());

            InputStream is = c.getInputStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4 * 1024];
            int len1 = 0;
            while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
            }
            fos.close();
            is.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        File file = new File(getFilesDir() + "/" + "Robotoo4.ttf");
        Log.d("", "onPostExecute: " + file.exists() + " " + file.getAbsolutePath() + " Length " + file.length() );
    }
}
```

Comment: What you want me to share..? DownloadingTask..?